# How to prevent a textbox from taking input when it reaches limit in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am taking input from a text box and counting number of characters excluding spaces, special characters and new line (enter)in java script, but i am unable to restrict the user to enter any type of characters till he edits the text entered where as i was able to block complete keyboard.
I am using the code below, can you please suggest me some additions so that i can add the above functionality.

```js
function countChars( countfrom, displayto ) {
    var val = document.getElementById( countfrom ).value, len;
    val = val.replace( /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/igm, "" );
    len = val.length;

    document.getElementById( displayto ).innerHTML = len;
    if ( len >= 9 ) {
        onkeydown = function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="data" cols="40" rows="5"
onkeyup="countChars('data','charcount');" onkeydown="countChars('data','charcount');" onmouseout="countChars('data','charcount');"></textarea><br>
<span id="charcount">0</span> Characters entered.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preventDefault()` is fine, but you should allow <kbd>backspace</kbd> and <kbd>delete</kbd> for the users to edit the text.

**Check below snippet:**

```js
function countChars(countfrom, displayto) {
  var val = document.getElementById(countfrom).value;
  val = val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/igm, "");
  var len = val.length;

  document.getElementById(displayto).innerHTML = len;

  onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46 && len >= 9)
      e.preventDefault();
  }

}
```

```html
<textarea id="data" cols="40" rows="5" onkeyup="countChars('data','charcount');" onkeydown="countChars('data','charcount');" onmouseout="countChars('data','charcount');"></textarea>
<br>
<span id="charcount">0</span> Characters entered.
```